# how can i make gevent application exit immediately after any exception?

Tags: python, exception, gevent

i'm working with an application written in python using gevent.  i want it to exit immediately as a result of any exception that i haven't explicitly trapped.

it looks like i'd have to patch the core gevent code.

is there any way can i do this in my app, without patching gevent or greenlet?

Comment: So wait, your application doesn't already exit when faced when an unhandled exception.

Comment: Uh, yeah, the default behaviour is to do this. Are you sure you are not doing some kind of ``catch Exception`` somewhere, catching everything?

Answer (score 4):

You you're using [version 1.0beta](http://code.google.com/p/gevent/downloads/list) then tweaking `gevent.get_hub().SYSTEM_ERROR` can help you. `SYSTEM_ERROR` lists exception types that, if caught by gevent, should be re-raised in the main greenlet.

By default, `SYSTEM_ERROR` is `(KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit, SystemError)`. Every other unhandled exception will be just reported but will not end the process (unless the original exception is raised in the main greenlet, in which case the usual happens).

You can modify SYSTEM_ERROR:

```
import gevent
gevent.spawn(int, "xxx").join()  # will merely report ValueError on stderr
gevent.get_hub().SYSTEM_ERROR += (ValueError, )
gevent.spawn(int, "xxx").join()  # will report ValueError, but then it will also re-raise it
```

See the [source where SYSTEM_ERROR is defined](https://bitbucket.org/denis/gevent/src/91bea46584c9/gevent/hub.py#cl-283).

If you set `SYSTEM_ERROR` to `BaseException`, then any unhandled exception will be considered fatal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `spawn_link_exception` instead of `spawn`.